# regular expression search and replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This is some code

```
<br />  <br />  <br />   <br /> <br />  <br />
```

but

I want replace

```
<br /> fourth with <hr />
```

And this output

```
<br />  <br />  <br />   <hr />  <br />   <br />
```

Please help me

Comment: your question is unintelligible, please explain what you're trying to do. and show what you have so far.

Comment: I want replac a subject phrase similar in different positions

Comment: As Amarghosh says below, your best bet is to use an HTML/DOM parser rather than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you want:

```
<?php

$text = <<<EOT

<br /> 1  <br /> 2 <br />  3  <br /> 4 <br /> 5  <br /> 6 
<br /> 7  <br /> 8 <br />  9  <br /> 10 <br /> 11  <br /> 12 
<br /> 13  <br /> 14 <br />  15  <br /> 16 <br /> 17  <br /> 18 

EOT;

$tag = '<br \\/>';
$content = '[^<]*';
print preg_replace("/($content(?:$tag$content){3})$tag/", '$1<BREAK! />', $text);


?>
```

The output ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Y0YbU)):

```
<br /> 1  <br /> 2 <br />  3  <BREAK! /> 4 <br /> 5  <br /> 6 
<br /> 7  <BREAK! /> 8 <br />  9  <br /> 10 <br /> 11  <BREAK! /> 12 
<br /> 13  <br /> 14 <br />  15  <BREAK! /> 16 <br /> 17  <br /> 18
```

That said, this is a pain and you really shouldn't be using regex for this.

---

If you only want to do one replacement, you can set the `limit` argument to [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace("/($content(?:$tag$content){3})$tag/", '$1<BREAK! />', $text, 1);
                                                                          ^^limit
```

Comment: Thanks for reply 
But I want replace only one position .

Comment: @Thoman: `preg_replace` has a `limit` argument; just set it to `1` (http://ideone.com/HKpjj)

Answer (score 1):

This will work only for the given case:

```
preg_replace("#<br /> 4#", "<hr /> 4", $str);
```

If you're looking for a generic solution, [RegEx is not the best tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for that. Use HTML/XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case:

```
s/<br \/> 4/<hr \/> 4/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regexp.

```
echo str_replace(' <br /> 4', ' <hr /> 4', $str);
```